# FTP Download in Android Extremely Slow (Fast in just Java)

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-commons, ftp-client

I am downloading MP3 files from an FTP server. It is for an Android application which will download and the then play the MP3 files. The downloading is implemented in Java using apache commons library and the code is largely based on another tutorial. The download works very fast on my desktop running Java taking about 5 seconds to download a file which is ~10mb, but on the same code run on an Android device (I have tried 2) is ridiculously slower taking 5-10 minutes to download the same file. (Both tests were done over Wifi).

Code based on: http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=28&cpage=2#comment-40

The code below shows the two methods used: connect and download.

```
    public boolean connect(String host, String username, String pass, int port){
    try{

        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

        if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                boolean loginStatus = mFTPClient.login(username,  pass);

                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                mFTPClient.setKeepAlive(true);

                return loginStatus;
        }


    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: Could not connect to: " + host);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

    public boolean download(String srcFilePath, String dstFilePath) {
    boolean downloadStatus = false;
    try {
        FileOutputStream dstFileStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFilePath);
        downloadStatus = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath,   dstFileStream);
        dstFileStream.close();
        return downloadStatus;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Failed to download file from " + srcFilePath + " to " + dstFilePath);
    }
    return downloadStatus;
}
```

Hopefully I have mentioned all the details needed and would appreciate if anyone could explain why it is so much slower and how if at all I can make it download in a reasonable time.

Comment: Did you compare speedtest.net desktop and mobile results? I have a Wi-Fi network at home, but I never could download something as fast as from PC.

Comment: Have just done and Speed Test gave ~26mb on mobile and ~29mb on desktop. However ping was much larger giving 23ms on desktop and 62ms on mobile. Could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Do you have another FTP client on your mobile? If yes, are the results comparable?

Comment: Have just tried that and it is fast, taking 5-6 seconds, so it must be the application and not the device

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stumbled accross a similar issue, solved it by changing the download buffer size.

What was strange is the same code was very fast on Android emulator x86, but painfully slow on the real device.

So, before calling the downloading function **retrieveFile**
add a line like this:

```
mFTPClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
```

Comment: This fixed a real pain in the but issue I was seeing on certain devices using ftp

Comment: the exact and to the point answer i was looking for , Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

So, before calling the downloading function `retrieveFile` add a line like this:

```
mFTPClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
```

This is the correct solution. My app was slow to download 10 files in 20 minutes. With this modification of buffer takes 1 minute. 
Genial. Thank you very much.